# Changing images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that changes images fine, but not smoothly. How can I change this so they change smoothly?

```
//--------AutoPlay select--------------------------
function autoPlaySlider(id){

    var recNumber = parseInt(id)+1;

    if(jQuery("#simg_"+recNumber).length){ 

        jQuery("#rt-header-surround")
            .attr("style",'background-image:url('+jQuery("#simg_"+recNumber).attr("imgpath")+')');

    }else{

        jQuery("#rt-header-surround")
            .fadeOut()
            .attr("style",'background-image:url('+jQuery("#simg_"+lastone).attr("imgpath")+')');

    }
}
```

Comment: Define *smoothly*, it's a vague word here.  Fading? Sizing?

Comment: @ErikPhilips if you notice `.fadeOut()` you'll know what efx OP wants. The issue is simply that fade will not apply to a background-image change (`.attr("style",'background-image`).

Comment: please put full code and html codes for trace it on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score -1):

$().fadeOut(); applies to the element, not it's background.

If you want to animate CSS properties your best bet is to use [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/);

Comment: Have two layers overlaying each other, set the current image to the front one, the next image to the behind layer, you can then use something like `$('#currentDiv').animate({backgroundPositionX: '-100%'})` to slide the image out, or `$('#currentDiv').animate({opacity:0})` to fade it out

Comment: `$().fadeOut();` sets `style="display: none;"` after the animation completes, if the container of the element in question has `auto` height, this will cause the container's height to change which usually isn't desired in cases such as a banner slider.

Comment: If you set fixed width/height + `position: relative` on the parent you could then `position: absolute` on it's children (the slides) and then the children won't stack on each other and will layer over each other instead.